# What error codes should I expect from Boost::filesystem::copy

Tags: c++, boost, errno, boost-filesystem

I'm trying to copy a file to a destination using boost::filesystem::copy_file with the system::error_code parameter, as I don't want exceptions thrown.

That function accepts a parameter whether it should fail if a file already exists with the same name, which is the behavior I want. From http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file:

> Effects: If option == copy_option::fail_if_exists && exists(to), an error is reported.

However, I can't find which error codes I should expect. Is that dependent on the underlying OS?

Comment: I think it's dependent on the OS and the filesystem.

Comment: [How to use error_code](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-3.html) (It's silly complicated)

Comment: You can at least use the system::error_code::operator ! to check if an error was detected or not. Depending on your use case this might be sufficient. (At least it was for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is dependent on the underlying OS. The source code shows that `copy_file()` (and other operations) generates errors like this:

```
  if (ec == 0)
    BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(filesystem_error(message,
      p, error_code(BOOST_ERRNO, system_category())));
  else
    ec->assign(BOOST_ERRNO, system_category());
```

`system_category()` specifies [errors originating from the operating system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html#system_category) and `BOOST_ERRNO` on Posix systems is [`errno`](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html).

On Posix, the underlying call to `open()` with `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` will fail and set `errno` to `EEXIST` when the file already exists.